# Find duplicates between two pandas based on lat, long intersect

Tags: python, pandas, geospatial

I have two pandas DataFrames with `Address, Lat and Long` as columns. I'd like to find rows that are duplicates between the 2 dataframes based on the intersection of their geocordinates. I'll define the logic for intersection as two points that within `50ft` of eachother.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'addr': ['NBC Tower, 455 N Cityfront Plaza Dr #2700, Chicago, IL 60611, United States','340 E North Water St, Chicago, IL 60611, United States'],
                    'Lat': [41.890100, 41.889680],
                    'Lon': [-87.621150, -87.618790]
                   })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'addr': ['455 N Cityfront Plaza Dr #2900, Chicago, IL 60611, United States','255 E Grand Ave, Chicago, IL 60611, United States'],
                    'Lat': [41.890100, 41.891392],
                    'Lon': [-87.621150, -87.621323] 
                   })
```

If the intersection between the coordinates is less than `50ft`, then insert `match`, otherwise insert `No match found`.

Would prefer to have a function that find the intersection and use `.apply`. Something like below:

```
def find_geomatch(args...):

    if match:

      txt = 'match'
 
    else:
   
      txt = 'No match found'

    return txt

df1['geomatch'] = df1.apply(lambda x: geomatch(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [scikit-learn implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html) of the haversine (great circle) distance formula:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances
from math import radians

for deg_col in ['Lat', 'Lon']:
    df1[f'{deg_col}_rad'] = df1[deg_col].apply(radians)
    df2[f'{deg_col}_rad'] = df2[deg_col].apply(radians)    

# haversine_distances assumes (lat, lon) order
distances = haversine_distances(df1[['Lat_rad', 'Lon_rad']], 
                                df2[['Lat_rad', 'Lon_rad']])

# Convert to km by multiplying by mean Earth radius in km
distances_in_km = distances * 6371

# Convert km to feet: ft = m/km * ft/m
distances_in_ft = distances_in_km * 1000 * 3.281

# Build a DataFrame with address strings in index and columns
res = pd.DataFrame(distances_in_ft, 
                  index=df1['addr'].rename('addr_df1'),
                  columns=df2['addr'].rename('addr_df2'))

# Reshape to long table of distance between each address pair
res = res.stack().rename('distance_in_feet').reset_index()

# Build geomatch column
res['geomatch'] = np.where(res['distance_in_feet'] <= 500, 'match', 'no match')

print(res.to_markdown(index=False))
```

| addr_df1 | addr_df2 | distance_in_feet | geomatch |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NBC Tower, 455 N Cityfront Plaza Dr #2700, Chicago, IL 60611, United States | 455 N Cityfront Plaza Dr #2900, Chicago, IL 60611, United States | 0 | match |
| NBC Tower, 455 N Cityfront Plaza Dr #2700, Chicago, IL 60611, United States | 255 E Grand Ave, Chicago, IL 60611, United States | 473.697 | match |
| 340 E North Water St, Chicago, IL 60611, United States | 455 N Cityfront Plaza Dr #2900, Chicago, IL 60611, United States | 659.015 | no match |
| 340 E North Water St, Chicago, IL 60611, United States | 255 E Grand Ave, Chicago, IL 60611, United States | 929.173 | no match |

Comment: I posted sample data on SO, in reality, my 2 `dfs` have different shapes 100 and 80. When you pass 2 `dfs` with different shape, what does it return? Is it pairwise distances between each point? The length of the array with distances is 80.

Comment: In the real dataframes, I have several columns (not just 3). How do you suggest I build the dataframe?

Comment: Hi @kms! Unequal length DataFrames won't be a problem: `haversine_distances(df1, df2)` returns a matrix of shape `len(df1), len(df2)`. So for example, if `df1` has 100 rows and `df2` has 80 rows, the result will have 100 rows and 80 columns. As for your extra columns, do the extra columns also hold coordinates? Or can you safely exclude them?

Comment: got it. To clarify, the `haversine_distances` is calculating the distance between each pair of `lat, lon` in `df1` with every pair in `df2`? Therefore, the resultant shape is 100*80 and each rows contains distances stored as `np.ndarray` of length 80. Correct?

Comment: The extra columns are not coordinates, once I have the pairwise distances in `df1` and I need to drop / exclude `rows` where `geomatch` is `match`.

Comment: Yep, that's right, haversine_distances computes pairwise distances, so the distance between each `lat, lon` entry in `df1` and each `lat, lon` in `df2`.

Comment: I got to the `distances_in_mi` step. The `len(distances_in_mi)` is 100 and `len(disances_in_mi[0])` is 80. Now, how do I exclude / drop rows from `df1` where distance is `<x` miles? That's the step I am stuck at.

Comment: Oh I see, how about `df1_cleaned = df1[df1['geomatch'] != 'match'].copy()`?